svelte 5 sveltekit spa object change detection
I started using Svelte-5 with Sveltekit as a SPA with Firebase.
In an update form I like to detect when fields change to show buttons like commit and reset when object props change.
Now I use something like this:
history = $State()

let delta = $derived({
    title: sectionObj.title,
    contra: sectionObj.contra,
    exposed: sectionObj.exposed,
    vat: sectionObj.vat,
    groupIds: JSON.stringify(sectionObj.groupIds.filter((g) => g !== '')),
    lookup: JSON.stringify(sectionObj.lookup),
    ignored: sectionObj.ignored,
    rename: sectionObj.rename,
});

onMount(() => {
    ...
    history = delta;
    
});

let equal = $derived(isEqual(history, delta));  // lodash

Other sugegstions?

Why would you want to do it differently?

Maybe I missed a smarter way to detect object changes

You could use a $state with an $effect to detect changes being made but using a comparison as you already do should be the only way to reliably detect that there are actually differences.
Users could change something and then change it again to revert it to the original value. This would not be captured by a changed flag that is being set to true via an $effect.
(The JSON.stringify calls might be unnecessary, isEqual performs a deep equality check. Some cloning may be necessary, though.)

Yes of course I don't need Json.stringify.
